# Using pandas groupby to find the average length of the text within each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm using the shakespeare corpus.

```
    act literature_type scene   scene_text  scene_title speaker title
0   1   Comedy  1   In delivering my son from me, I bury a second ...   Rousillon. The COUNT's palace.  COUNTESS    All's Well That Ends Well
1   1   Comedy  1   And I in going, madam, weep o'er my father's d...   Rousillon. The COUNT's palace.  BERTRAM All's Well That Ends Well
2   1   Comedy  1   You shall find of the king a husband, madam; y...   Rousillon. The COUNT's palace.  LAFEU   All's Well That Ends Well
3   1   Comedy  1   What hope is there of his majesty's amendment?  Rousillon. The COUNT's palace.  COUNTESS    All's Well That Ends Well
4   1   Comedy  1   He hath abandoned his physicians, madam; under...   Rousillon. The COUNT's palace.  LAFEU   All's Well That Ends Well
```

I'd like to find the average `scene_text` length for each title.

I thought to use something along the lines of:

```
all_works_by_speaker_df.groupby('title').apply(lambda x: np.mean(len(x)))
```

This just returns the number of scenes in each title.

Comment: length = number of words or number of characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If need `len`s of characters:

```
df = (all_works_by_speaker_df.groupby('title')['scene_text']
                            .apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.str.len()))
                            .reset_index(name='mean_len_text'))
print (df)

                       title  mean_len_text
0  All's Well That Ends Well           48.4
```

If need `len`s of words use [Vaishali's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459952/2901002).

Comment: Would the len mean words or characters? Not very clear

Comment: This is for characters, your solution is for word length. Thank you both!

Comment: @jezrael you seem to mocked up an actual DF - I'd be curious to check our answers produce the same result and how the timings vary (if you have a minute :p)

Comment: I am now offline, only on phone... so unfortunately cannot do it. (:

Answer (score 4):

Take the lengths of the strings from the column, then groupby an array which is your play title, then apply the mean.

```
mean_len = df.scene_text.str.len().groupby(df.title).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

Split, len and mean

```
df.groupby('title').scene_text.apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str.len().mean())


title
All's Well That Ends Well    9.2
```